# How do I run custom commands and deploy a build folder using the heroku deployment on codeship

Tags: heroku, npm, codeship

I need to run `npm run build --release` and only deploy the files in my build folder.  How do I configure codeship heroku deployment to do so.  Should I add custom steps to the test settings?

I could create a custom script deployment step but I would like to use the heorku configuration that's built in to codeship if I can.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The integrated Heroku deployment on Codeship is based on running a git push, so you would need to run the `npm run build --release` command, and then commit those changes to the repository.

That would also require you to enable force pushing to the remote repository on Heroku as the next build (triggered by GitHub/Bitbucket/Gitlab) would not include that auto-generated commit.

That said, we built a script to deploy to Heroku based on their build API, which is available at https://github.com/codeship-library/heroku-deployment/blob/master/scripts/codeship_heroku_deploy

It is intended to be used by our Docker based platform (called Codeship Pro), but the same commands would work as a custom script deployment on Codeship Basic as well.

Comment: Committing files which are the output of the build process into source control is definitely not the right pattern.

Comment: Yeah, I agree it's not the right pattern. This is a workaround for the specific use case asked about in the question. There are other ways to deploy to Heroku as well, and I included a link to a deployment script that uses an approach based on copying files instead of doing a `git push` instead as well.